# Creative dual NMOS and PMOS switch

Tags: arduino, power, mosfet, switches, gpio

I have quite a strange requirement for one of my assignments for a job interview. The goal is to design a shield to measure current through a 12V power rail. Part of this design is an on and off switch for the power 12V rail using both an NMOS and PMOS MOSFET set up controlled by an Arduino Uno. The confusion is the requirement states to only use 1 GPIO pin later in the text to do this.

The reason I'm confused is this can easily be achieved only using a high-side switch with the PMOS, and not needing the NMOS. I've tried considering using two GPIO pins to have both a high-side and a low-side switch, but I don't really see the point in doing so since it would work the same just with extra steps and components.

TLDR:
Is there some creative technique where one would use both a NMOS and PMOS to control the output of the 12V power rail using a single GPIO pin?

Even if your answer doesn't solve this, I'd still like to hear some creative ideas to try and use both to make a more robust system.

Comment: Consider the gate threshold of the PMOS and the output voltage of an Arduino and I'm sure you'll see why you need the NMOS with the PMOS - and just one GPIO pin.

Comment: The Arduino can't directly drive the gate of a P-channel MOSFET whose source is tied to 12V. That's what the NMOS is for.

Comment: Thank you!

I forgot about the level shifters to make this work.